# Problem accessing Internet from old phones/PDAs (HTTPS, SSL, certificates, compatible services,....)

Tags: internet, network, palm, windows-mobile, pda

How to connect 18-12 years non supported OSes/devices to Internet?
Specifically PDAs and phones, that are more limited to use additional components/accesories?

(*) Answer related to computers can be also interesting but they will have less limitations and issues, as there are some operating systems that were receiving updates on protocols, apps and webbrowsers.

As the purpose is recreational and curiosity, the lack security using obsolete platforms is not a problem.

What **technologies and services** will fail (have changed and have not backwards compatibility) and which ones are still working fine?

What So you think about old devices and the **usage of the following technologies/protocols**?

**Connection technology and possible limitations:**

- SIM card

  - incompatible format (size)
  - incompatible security/encryption ¿have you tried a new SIM in an old phone?
- Wifi

  - incompatibilities with Mode/Speed  ¿can modern AP and router work in mode B?
  - security protocols. ¿can modern HW be set to be insecure?
- Bluetooth DUN
- Bluetooth tethering
- Ethernet compatibility

**Internet services for testing (failing, working):**

- Web

  - Issues with protocols
  - Issues with technologies
  - Compatible webpages (for testing)
- Other technologies

  - RSS
  - IM (jabber,....
  - gopher
  - others
- email

  - Issues with protocols
  - Compatible services (POP3/SMTP)
- Others

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I suspect what you are asking is "What modern commonly used Internet technologies will fail on old (>15 yrs) devices"?  I think the answer is modern Javascript and modern SSL, both of which require a recently updated browser (or software library if run outside of the browser).

Comment: @JimNelson The statement was not the usability of old web pages in new browsers, but new web pages in old browsers. They really don't work. A lot of new standards appeared and backward compatibility became a no-issue.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I deleted my comment shortly after posting it (but apparently after you'd read it).

Comment: @BrianH yes the new Web will fail at 99%, because the code and because the resources required. But Also i am sure that there is webpages that still using old technologies so the can be used for testing. Before loading a web you need to connect to network, you will face other problems such as your home wifi or compatibility with your SIM card

Comment: @knol I have tried to improve the question and the focus. Target is to identify all /most technologies that will fail but also identify what is still working, so allow testing. I can separate in 2 different questions but IMHO "go/no-go" info in this case is complementary.

Comment: “Improving a question’s focus” doesn’t mean “listing everything you’d like to see described”, it means reducing the question’s scope (in this case, drastically). Your question is far, far too broad.

Comment: Although improved by the edit, this is still something of a list question and therefore very broad for the StackExchange format.  However, there is some merit in it.  After all, there are still Telnet and Gopher servers out there if you want to play.  I've reopened the question and lets see if the community runs with it or decides to close it again.

Comment: Now it's a bit more readable and thus making it rather clear that doesn't really fit. For one it doesn't ask for a clear topic, but half of of the communication domain at once, but also doesn't look for a specific answer, but a broad list. So either make it a real question or close again.

Comment: You wil most likely find that the internet is a boring place as your certificates are outdated so anything httpssy will not work.

Comment: yes @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and it is one of the reason of this question, conect to Internet is difficult but when you success you don't know how to check. A list of non SSL urls and compatible with old HTML would be a huge help. I found 3 non SSL urls. A non SSL access to wikipedia would be great.

Comment: @DanielPerez Lost cause.  Install a remote desktop client and access a modern machine.

Comment: Please narrow your question down to one device, protocol, or service, and explain what doesn't work and what you've tried. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the HTTPS today. There is a huge push to migrate off of HTTP and on to HTTPS. But older machines simply can't do the necessary encryption in time.

But much of this can be mitigate off-device by routing through a proxy that takes HTTP traffic on one side (device side), and talks HTTPS out the other (internet side). It's not drag and drop, but it's doable.

After that it's a content problem. As a consumer, there's not much we can do about the content issue. You can potentially lower the complexity of pages by "looking like" a mobile device (mobile site can trend toward a simpler presentation), but even still you'd potentially face crippled sites when Javascript does not work.

A good way to check this out is to use a terminal based browser, like `lynx`. While it certainly supports HTTPS, it doesn't support (I don't believe) CSS or Javascript. So, using this can give folks a better idea what a tech limited view of a website might be.

As for other protocols, we find today that chips the bridge protocols for smaller microcontrollers have more computing capacity than the devices we try to connect just to keep up with the protocol. The "universal" adapter today is USB. There's pretty much a bridge from USB to most anything: Ethernet, Bluetooth, IDE, SCSI, etc.

Get USB connectivity to the device, then everything is but a proper driver away.

Mind, it's not "easy", but it's possible. There are several SPI interfaces to USB adapters. Most devices aren't "real time", and designed to be buffered, so with proper handshaking, your glacial ancient device will be able to readily read and write to others via USB.

Comment: Extra performance required for Secure pages is bad  but in any event  many old devices doesn't have webbrowser that support HTTPS :( A proxy service that transform HTTPS in HTTP seems a good solution. Do you know any?  Regarding USB interfaces is seems great for computers but i think it will no apply to old phones and PDAs.

Comment: @DanielPerez I'm not sure if it'd apply to everything, but I used [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/) to terminate the TLS on an IRC connection before it reached Pidgin to work around its intentional lack of a "This is supposed to be self-signed. Stop bugging me." checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

For web pages, you can use the [Web rendereing proxy](https://github.com/tenox7/wrp), displaying modern web pages inside a GIF and imagemap. It works well, though Google Captcha often thinks (rightfully) that it is not a human controlling the web browser and won't let you through.

For pretty much anything else, you can try to locate a VNC client for your platform, There are clients [even for ZX Spectrum](https://github.com/rkd77/zxvnc) and [MS DOS](http://vncviewer8086.sourceforge.net/), albeit the latter is not quite finished and the former does not use the VNC protocol (therefore should not be called as such). This of course assumes your platform can display graphics at all (no IBM PC with MDA). Although you probably have to de-configure modern security settings (like encryption) at the server side. Expect problems with entering non-ASCII characters, fancy keyboard layout and scrollwheel.