# Internet services that are still compatible with devices (phones/pdas from 2000-2007)

Tags: internet, palm, pda, backward-compatibility

Though I can identify some technologies like following, I would like to know which ones will surely fail and which ones are worth to test on my old Palm, Symbian, WindowsCE,...

```
Web
    Issues with protocols (HTTPS will be a no go for sure)
    Issues with web technologies (css, modern javascript and web2.0 will be a problem too)
    Compatible webpages (services with a view or that are still on HTTP, HTML1)
Other technologies
    RSS
    IM (jabber,....
    gopher
    ...
email
    Issues with protocols
    Compatible services (POP3/SMTP)
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem accessing Internet from old phones/PDAs (HTTPS, SSL, certificates, compatible services,....)](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15066/problem-accessing-internet-from-old-phones-pdas-https-ssl-certificates-compa)

Comment: This is a subset of [your previous question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15066/79), and still suffers from the same problems as that one.

Comment: yes, @StephenKitt  it is subset because the original question was closed before having good answers and also it was recommended to make a more focused questions. I think this one is very focused. Or do you  think that it is appropriate to make question for 10 devices and 10 services/protocols (100)? I would like to see your proposal for reducing the scope of the question

Comment: I don’t think a question which lists “Others” three times can count as “very focused”. If you were to ask, for example, “Of the services which my Palm OS 4 device from 2000 could access back then, which are still usable now?”, that would be a more appropriate question.

Comment: The amount of potential accessible services are not related to Palm or Symbian and its preinstalled apps. These devices are limited by their OS and supported protocols. Destination services are too many and it has sense toi discuss in general because very likely they can work on other devices with similar age and limits.